# Find the most expensive item in an array of items in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, max

So I got some homework, In which I have a class `FoodItem` and class `Stock`. in class 'Stock' there is an array of `FoodItem` (`_stock`) and integer of the current position in the array (`_noOfFoodItems`).

One of the assignments is to find the most expensive item in the array (one of the class properties of `FoodItem` is `int  _price`). another instruction is, that if the array is empty the method should return `null`. I have written to every property `get` and `set` methods.

At first, it seems to me just like any other "find the biggest item in an array" questions, but I seem to struggle with it for some reason. Here is what I came out with so far:

```
public FoodItem mostExpensive() {
  if (_noOfFoodItems == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  FoodItem mostExpensiveFoodItem = _stock[0];

  for (int i = 0 ; i< _noOfFoodItems; i++) {
    if (_stock[i].getPrice() > mostExpensiveFoodItem.getPrice()) {
             mostExpensiveFoodItem = new FoodItem(_stock[i]);
    }
  }
  return mostExpensiveFoodItem;   
}
```

I really have no idea what went wrong. the IDE that the university tells us to use has no debug features in it, and the code seems fine to me.

I have tested it out and the method returned the first item rather than the most expensive one.

can you tell what am I doing wrong?
if you believe that the error has to do with other parts of the code, tell me which part to add.

thank you in advance!

**edit**

the conductor I use in the method is the following:

```java
 public FoodItem(FoodItem otherFoodItem)
     {
        this._name = otherFoodItem.getName();
        this._catalogueNumber = otherFoodItem.getCatalogueNumber();
        this._quantity = otherFoodItem.getQuantity();
        this._prodactionDate = otherFoodItem.getProdactionDate();
        this._expiryDate = otherFoodItem.getExpiryDate();
        this._minTemperature = otherFoodItem.getMinTemperature();
        this._maxTemperature = otherFoodItem.getMaxTemperature();
     }
```

My testing main:

```java
public static void Main (String[] Args)
    {
    Stock s = new Stock();
     s.addItem(new FoodItem ("milk", 1111, 5, new Date (30, 5, 2003), new Date (31, 5, 2003), -16, 22, 17 ));
     s.addItem(new FoodItem ("milk", 1111, 3, new Date (30, 5, 2003), new Date (31, 5, 2003), -16, 22, 17 ));
     s.addItem(new FoodItem ("bread", 1112, 2, new Date (7, 6, 2001), new Date (13, 6, 2002), -7, 1, 13 ));
     s.addItem(new FoodItem ("corn", 1113, 1, new Date (30, 5, 2001), new Date (30, 5, 2000), -16, 22, 18 ));
     s.addItem(new FoodItem ("soup", 1111, 5, new Date (30, 5, 2003), new Date (31, 5, 2003), -16, 22, 17 ));
     s.addItem(new FoodItem ("hot dog", 1114, 201, new Date (30, 5, 2007), new Date (31, 5, 2003), 7, 5, 1 ));

     System.out.println(s.mostExpensive().getName());
    }
```

the "regular" constactor:

```java
public FoodItem (String name, long catalogueNumber, int quantity, Date prodactionDate, Date expiryDate, int minTemperature, int maxTemperature, int price)
     {
        this._name = name;    
        this._catalogueNumber = catalogueNumber;   
        this._quantity = quantity;   
         this._price = price;
        if(prodactionDate.before(expiryDate))
         this._expiryDate =  prodactionDate.tomorrow();
         else
         this._expiryDate =  expiryDate;
        if(minTemperature > maxTemperature)
        {
        this._minTemperature = maxTemperature;   
        this._maxTemperature = minTemperature;   
        }
        else
        {
        this._minTemperature = minTemperature;  
        this._maxTemperature = maxTemperature;
        }

     }
```

Comment: Is the First item the most expensive Food item ?

Comment: @Geek No, he is the second most expensive ```FoodItem```

Comment: Your code either never enters the loop or never enters the If condition. It is as simple as that. Try initializing mostExpensiveFoodItem with _stock[1] and see if this returns the 0th element or 1st element. If it retturns the 1st element than the problem is with the loop or If condition if it returns 0th element than 0th is the greatest element. Try it.

Comment: Your conductor doesn't have a Price attribute ? Add that also else it might be initializing the default value to Price.

Comment: @Geek I will add my testing Main.

Comment: If you can't use debugging tools in your IDE, I would recommend adding System.out.println() statements to your code sot hat you can follow the steps it takes - for example does it ever enter the loop? Does the FoodItem return the correct value? Logically it looks correct but without seeing the whole program it would be impossible to know where the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new FoodItem when the next item in stock is more expensive, but you want to make the mostExpensiveFoodItem to BE the next item in stock.

Change:

```java
mostExpensiveFoodItem = new FoodItem(_stock[i]);
```

to

```java
mostExpensiveFoodItem = _stock[i];
```

if that isn't the error I don't see why the code is wrong so it's probably somewhere else

**Edit for your constructor**

Your constructor for copying the FoodItem doesn't set the price, so if you create a new FoodItem the price equals null and therefore the first FoodItem always has the highest price, since it is the only one you created regularilly.

Change your constructor:

```java
 public FoodItem(FoodItem otherFoodItem)
     {
        this._name = otherFoodItem.getName();
        this._catalogueNumber = otherFoodItem.getCatalogueNumber();
        this._quantity = otherFoodItem.getQuantity();
        this._prodactionDate = otherFoodItem.getProdactionDate();
        this._expiryDate = otherFoodItem.getExpiryDate();
        this._minTemperature = otherFoodItem.getMinTemperature();
        this._maxTemperature = otherFoodItem.getMaxTemperature();

        //ADD THIS
        this._price = otherFoodItem.getPrice();
     }
```

Comment: this is the contractors they told us to use for the assignment of one ```FoodItem``` to another. It just copies all the values from the param to a new ```FoodItem```

Comment: can you add the constructor to your post?

Answer (score 0):

int  _price is missing in your FoodItem constructor. Therefore, _stock[i].getPrice() > mostExpensiveFoodItem.getPrice() is never true and returns first element of array every time.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write your `mostExpensive` like below which helps you to find the problem by yourself.

```
public FoodItem mostExpensive(double highestPrice, FoodItem[] stock) {
  if (stock == null || stock.length == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  FoodItem mostExpensiveFoodItem = stock[0];

  for (int i = 0 ; i < stock.length; i++) {
    if (stock[i].getPrice() > highestPrice) {
             mostExpensiveFoodItem = stock[i];
    }
  }
  return mostExpensiveFoodItem;   
}
```

Comment: but this takes params and the instruction says no param.

Comment: In that case I would implement `Comparable` into `FoodItem` class and just use `Collections.sort()` and get the most expensive item in just 2 lines of code.

Comment: I wish... but we may not use any extension method except the ```Math``` class